# PHP: include(...); in a variable

Tags: php, variables, include

I'm trying to include my AdSense code inside a variable like this:

```
$ad = include_once('../adsense/ad.php');
echo $ad;
```

In `ad.php` I'm doing this:

```
<?php
  return '<script>...</script>';
?>
```

It's showing my AsSense ad but only once. After that, it's outputting `1`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called `include_once()`, so the file will only be included one time. After that, it will return `TRUE` because the call succeeded, but no new content was included.  Use plain `include()` instead if you need to use it multiple times.

```
$ad = include('../adsense/ad.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

use `include` instead of `include_once`.  That, or only call `include_once` once ;)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Looks like the downvote was undone. Maybe a misclick

Comment: @Michael - That's true, it's hard to tell. I just wanted to put my 2 cents in.

Answer (score 2):

I think you *may* be better off using a function for this. You can get the same result, in a much more 'conventional' manner.

Using return in an include will work with include instead of include_once, as mentionned in other answers,  *but keep in mind* include used in this manner makes for non-conventional code structures, harder to re-use, won`t show up in function list definition, among other inconveniances.

Comment: I've actually was trying to do the same thing with ads, and only showing them at certain times and I was using variables but I eventually just used functions. It will save you a lot of time in the long run. `function echo_ad(){
include('../adsense/ad.php');
}` and then call the function where ever instead of echoing out the variable